# Site Content overflows into footer

Tags: css, layout, footer

http://jsfiddle.net/talmuda3/s9QyR/

```
footer {
    margin-top: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20em;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The layout of an offline website is tricky. The content overflows into the footer.
Part of the code is as above.

How can the content be adjusted so the footer remains at the bottom, and the content stretches across the site without overlapping the footer. Please be gentle. Checked Chris Coyier's site for any tips - might just have missed something. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing the article down with the `top: 12em` declaration. You should give the footer the same property, which fixes the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/s9QyR/1/

Answer (score 0):

you should also push footer `top:12em;`  that will add footer in right position. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s9QyR/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/s9QyR/10/)

```
article {
    margin-top:12em;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    padding: 1em;
    z-index: 2;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: visible;
}

footer {
    margin-top: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20em;
}
```

It seems that changing the positioning broke the natural flow of your elements.

You may want to try this method to avoid having to position everything down the line.

Comment: Also you had both 'width:100%;' and 'width:80%;' on your article.